# Is it possible to define a macro which handles grammatical cases?

Tags: macros, rust

I'd like to define a macro `callme` which can be applied like this.

```
fn main() {
    let a=4;
    let b=5;
    callme!(
        a (b) => { a+b } ;
        a (b) => { a*b } ;
        a (b) ~ C
    );
}
```

I do not know how to get a working macro definition for `callme`. Currently I'm trying something like this:

```
macro_rules! callme {
    (
        $($A: ident ($B: ident) => {$E: expr}) ; *
    ) => (
        $(
            println!("{:?} {:?} {:?}", $A, $B, $E);
        ) *
    );
    (
        $($A: ident ($B: ident) ~ $Q: ident) ; *
    ) => (
        $(
            println!("We got {:?} . {:?} . {:?}", $A, $B, $Q);
        ) *
    );
}
```

This does not work, because I cannot use both syntax cases at once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're working with a token stream, it's easier to leave it to recursion to process your pieces in cases like this. You could for instance do:

```
macro_rules! callme {
    ($A:ident ($B:ident) => { $E:expr }; $($rest:tt)*) => {
        println!("{:?} {:?} {:?}", $A, $B, $E);

        callme!($($rest)*);
    };
    ($A:ident ($B:ident) ~ $Q:ident; $($rest:tt)*) => {
        println!("We got {:?} . {:?} . {:?}", $A, $B, $Q);

        callme!($($rest)*);
    };
    () => {};
}

fn main() {
    let a=4;
    let b=5;
    let c = "C";
    callme!(
        a (b) => { a+b } ;
        a (b) => { a*b } ;
        a (b) ~ c;
    );
}
```

([On Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6576bbf7f814c8f7741c831b3d1f1614&version=stable))

Note that after each set of tokens, you gather all the remaining tokens and leave them to be handled by a later call to `callme!`, with a final `() => {}` to indicate a completion condition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works! Your answer helped me to understand token streams for rust macros. Sadly, I cannot +1 your answer yet.